# How to control the output of thrown errors in firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm using async/await in my firebase functions, which each call has the potential to throw an error. I'm not certain how to properly handle catching each error. I would like to not wrap every call in a try/catch since the amount of code involved almost defeats the purpose of using the await syntax.

If I let my awaits throw then firebase-functions will catch and log them, which is great. However, I don't want these errors propagated back to the client.

How can I capture all thrown errors and control the returned response?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**. Giant try/catch:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  // Get the data from the request
  const input1 = req.body.input1
  const input2 = req.body.input2

  try {
    // First bit of await work
    const fileInfo = await db.getFileInfo(input2)

    // Do some non-await work
    const tempFilePath = generateUniqueTempFilePath(fileInfo)

    // More await work
    await storage.download(input1, tempFilePath)
    const checkinResult = await db.checkin(tempFilePath, data)

    const result = { checkinResult, fileInfo }
    res.json(result)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message)
  }
}
```

One solution is to wrap all your await calls and associated logic in a separate function and try/catch it once in your endpoint method.

**Example**. Small try/catch and a separate function:

```
const service = require('./serviceA')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  // Get the data from the request
  const input1 = req.body.input1
  const input2 = req.body.input2

  // Perform async code in a single call
  var result = undefined
  try {
    result = await service.perform(input1, input2)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message)
    return
  }
  res.json(result)
}
```

and

```
async function perform (input1, input2) {
  // First bit of await work (no try/catch!)
  const fileInfo = await db.getFileInfo(input2)

  // Do some non-await work
  const tempFilePath = generateUniqueTempFilePath(fileInfo)

  // More await work (but they should throw errors with suitable messages!)
  await storage.download(input1, tempFilePath)
  const checkinResult = await db.checkin(tempFilePath, data)

  return { checkinResult, fileInfo }
}

module.exports = { perform }
```

Comment: This is my current understanding of the solution. I agree that I should separate out my logic and the network code. Generally, I prefer to have a unique error message for each unique point of error. Are you aware of any firebase specific solution?